# Shiny App doesn't increment variables as I would expect

Tags: r, shiny

I cannot understand why the current_row variable is reset to its initial value between presses of the prior and next buttons.

TY

```
current_row = 0

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("next_button", "next"),
    actionButton("previous_button", "previous")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$next_button, 
                 {
                   current_row = current_row + 1 
                   print (current_row)
                 }) 

    observeEvent(input$previous_button, 
                 {
                   current_row = current_row - 1 
                   print (current_row)
                 }) 
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_row = current_row + 1` in `observeEvent` does not actually update the `current_row` value in global environment. You need `<<-`. However using this in `shiny` is highly unadvised. Consider asking a separate question about what exactly you need so that people can point you in the right direction.

```
current_row = 0

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("next_button", "next"),
    actionButton("previous_button", "previous")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$next_button, 
                 {
                   current_row <<- current_row + 1 
                   print (current_row)
                 }) 

    observeEvent(input$previous_button, 
                 {
                   current_row <<- current_row - 1 
                   print (current_row)
                 }) 
  }
)
```